# Gradient view doesn't cover the whole width of the collection view Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, gradient

I'm trying to apply a gradient to a view that is a constraint to the top, left, and right of the collection view but for some reason, the gradient doesn't cover the whole width of the view that is applied to (see the red in the picture).

**View Controller Code:-**

```
extension HomeView : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
    cell.storyImage.image = UIImage(named: storyImages[indexPath.item].mediaURL ?? EMPTY_STR)
    cell.gradientView.frame = cell.storyImage.frame
    return cell
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
  }
}
```

**Cell Code:-**

```
import UIKit

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var sImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var gradientView: GradientView!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }
}

class GradientView: UIView {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor,UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
   }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image: ScreenShot]

**Main Storyboard**

[image: ScreenShot]

Question: How to set the width according to the collection view width?

Can someone please explain to me how to do this, I've tried with the above code but have no results yet. Please Correct me if I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `awakeFromNib`, the cell has the frame set in the xib/storyboard. When resized, the cell frame change, but not the gradient frame. You need to listen to layout change, and update the frame of the gradient there.

Comment: Why not with constraints?

Comment: @Larme, I'm trying but still same issue.

Comment: In `CollectionCell`: `override func layoutSubviews() { super.layoutSubviews(); gradientView.frame = bounds }`? and don't modify it elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

It happens because cell's contenview frame not updating. As the comment says , contentView's frame is equal to same in xib/storyboard frame in `awakeFromNib`. Use `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` in `cellForRowAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
    cell.contenView.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.storyImage.image = UIImage(named: storyImages[indexPath.item].mediaURL ?? EMPTY_STR)
    cell.gradientView.frame = cell.storyImage.frame
    return cell
```

}

In your cell class ,set layer's frame in layoutsubview function

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue Omer.

Comment: try calling `layoutIfNeeded()` from delegate method `func collectionView(UICollectionView, willDisplay: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt: IndexPath)`. The datasource method `cellForItemAt ` is just to create the cell and return. You will never get correct frame over here.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your `cellForItemAt` code is a little confusing:

```
cell.gradientView.frame = cell.storyImage.frame
```

In your Storyboard Prototype cell, you should constrain the `gradientView` to the `storyImage` view they will both be the same size.

Also, if you change your `GradientView` class to this, you don't have to worry about making separate calls to layout the gradient layer's frame:

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    
    lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor,UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Trying with your code, the gradient is working, but not in the correct points. It's showing left to right, but I want only the top to the middle top. Please check the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jKOp.png).

Comment: @ShamDhiman - I don't understand what you mean by *"only the top to the middle top."* ??

Comment: Means only top to bottom not left to right.

Comment: @ShamDhiman - do you mean you want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/USEev.png ??? or maybe this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufw6I.png ??? If neither of those, show an image of what you ***DO*** want.

Comment: only Need https://i.stack.imgur.com/USEev.png , this one but in horizontal way.

Comment: @ShamDhiman - then constrain the `gradientView` top/leading/bottom to the `storyImage`, and constrain its width equal to the `storyImage` width with a multiplier of `0.5`